# Views/Views slideshow confusion

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to create a slideshow that would be showing 3 instances of my custom contant type "Slideshow Image".
After spending hours without any success I've decided to seek help! I noticed that Views changed a lot when I updated all modules, and it seems as if Slideshow is not among the options for display under "Format" in the control panel of my view. I have Grid, HTML list, Jump menu, Table, Unformatted list but no slideshow. Now, I think I remember seeing "slideshow" as an option before "Views" changed! My questions are:

1. Have Views changed so that Slideshow is no longer an option for display? Am I going insane?
2. If it has, what is the new way of doing things?
3. If it hasn't, what could I be doing wrong?
4. There is a module called "Views Slideshow". It seems to not be fully ready for Drupal 7 yet. Do I need it? Is that my only option (as a Drupal & web programming newbie)?

Can anybody please help me clear this out?

Comment: Ok, now I'm able to answer my own questions:

1. : Dont know.
2. : See #4
3. : n/a
4. : "Do I need it?" - Yes! "Is that my only option?" - Don't know.

I installed Views Slideshow and a jquery file called cycle something. The jquery file was asked for by the Views module when it was needed, it even provided a link to it. Nice. I like the new Views module a lot better! 

Next challenge will be to add a custom style to the image slider...

Answer (score 1):

Views Slideshow does not come with the views module. Therefore you will not see it by default.  You have to download and enable the [views_slideshow module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to see this option.

There is alot of other contrib slideshow modules as well

Related modules

- [Views Slideshow Menu](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_menu)
- [Views Slideshow Slider](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_slider)
- [Views Slideshow Imageflow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_imageflow)
- [Views Slideshow Dynamic Display Block](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_ddblock)  (My Favourite of this list)
- [Views Slideshow Galleria](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_galleria)
- [Views Slideshow JCarousel Thumbs](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarouselthumbs)
- [Views Slideshow Xtra](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_xtra)

Most of these module does not have a supported Drupal 7 version,  however most of their Drupal 7 dev version will be stable enough to use.  I know I have used views_slideshow_ddblock without any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 modules usually need a bit to catch up as they're all so new. You should always be using the dev versions unless this is a production site. I believe Views 3 (which it sounds like you're using) was a significant update that required a little more than just running the update.

Views Slideshow gives the following warning:

> If you don't have
>   http://drupal.org/project/libraries
>   module enabled then please enable that
>   module before you upgrade to the
>   latest alpha release of version 3. It
>   is now a required module and you will
>   receive a fatal error if you don't
>   have that module enabled first. See
>   this issue for ways to fix it if you
>   receive the fatal error.

http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow